# Need Help Unbricking Samsung S3 (GT-i9300)

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-3, clockworkmod-recovery, unbricking, heimdall

below is a full and detailed account of what I have tried so far and where I think may be problems. I need someone with experience/in-depth knowledge of these sort of issues to give me a hand.

Okay so yesterday I had left my phone, a bit over 2 year old Samsung Galaxy S3 (GT-i9300) running M12 Snapshot of CyanogenMod11, all on it's own for around an hour and a half and when I got back to it it was stuck in bootloop at the "Samsung Galaxy SIII" screen. I successfully booted into recovery (ClockwrockMod Recovery v6.0.4.6) but get the error:

```
E:Can't mount /cache/recovery/command
E:Can't mount /cache/recovery/log
E:Can't open /cache/recovery/log
E:Can't mount /cache/recovery/last_log
E:Can't open /cache/recovery/last_log
E:Can't mount /cache/recovery/last_install
E:Can't open /cache/recovery/last_install
```

Similarly when I move into mounts and storage and try and mount anything but `storage/sdcard1` I get the message (using `/data` for example) `Error mounting /data!`.

Research lead me to believe that my best chance at recovering my Recovery, and from there Android itself was to re-flash CWM. As I wasn't able to get to Android, I tried to reach the bootloader but was only able to reach the Download mode for use by Odin/Heimdall.

I connected my device to my computer (Ubuntu 14.04) and ran Heimdall. Detect picks up the device and I can typically get the PIT, however when I try and flash recovery I get the below:

```
jake@jake-Aspire-5750:~/Downloads$ sudo heimdall flash --RECOVERY recovery.img --verbose --stdout-errors
Heimdall v1.4.0

Copyright (c) 2010-2013, Benjamin Dobell, Glass Echidna
http://www.glassechidna.com.au/

This software is provided free of charge. Copying and redistribution is
encouraged.

If you appreciate this software and you would like to support future
development please consider donating:
http://www.glassechidna.com.au/donate/

Initialising connection...
Detecting device...
      Manufacturer: "SAMSUNG"
           Product: "Gadget Serial"

            length: 18
      device class: 2
               S/N: 0
           VID:PID: 04E8:685D
         bcdDevice: 021B
   iMan:iProd:iSer: 1:2:0
          nb confs: 1

interface[0].altsetting[0]: num endpoints = 1
   Class.SubClass.Protocol: 02.02.01
       endpoint[0].address: 83
           max packet size: 0010
          polling interval: 09

interface[1].altsetting[0]: num endpoints = 2
   Class.SubClass.Protocol: 0A.00.00
       endpoint[0].address: 81
           max packet size: 0200
          polling interval: 00
       endpoint[1].address: 02
           max packet size: 0200
          polling interval: 00
Claiming interface...
Attempt failed. Detaching driver...
Claiming interface again...
Setting up interface...

Initialising protocol...
ERROR: Failed to receive handshake response.ERROR: Failed to receive handshake response. Retrying...
 Retrying...
Protocol initialisation successful.

Beginning session...

Some devices may take up to 2 minutes to respond.
Please be patient!

Session begun.

Downloading device's PIT file...
PIT file download successful.

Uploading RECOVERY
0%
14%

28%

42%

57%

71%

85%

99%

100%
ERROR: Failed to unpack received packet.
ERROR: Failed to unpack received packet.


ERROR: Failed to confirm end of file transfer sequence!
ERROR: Failed to confirm end of file transfer sequence!
ERROR: RECOVERY upload failed!

ERROR: (null) upload failed!

Ending session...
ERROR: libusb error -7 whilst sending packet.ERROR: libusb error -7 whilst sending packet. Retrying...
 Retrying...
ERROR: libusb error -7 whilst sending packet.ERROR: libusb error -7 whilst sending packet. Retrying...
 Retrying...
ERROR: libusb error -7 whilst sending packet.ERROR: libusb error -7 whilst sending packet. Retrying...
 Retrying...
ERROR: libusb error -7 whilst sending packet.ERROR: libusb error -7 whilst sending packet. Retrying...
 Retrying...
ERROR: libusb error -7 whilst sending packet.ERROR: libusb error -7 whilst sending packet. Retrying...
 Retrying...
ERROR: libusb error -7 whilst sending packet.ERROR: libusb error -7 whilst sending packet.

ERROR: Failed to send end session packet!
ERROR: Failed to send end session packet!
Releasing device interface...
Re-attaching kernel driver...
```

This happens every single time and my phone is currently a rather expensive and useless brick. I have searched around an can't find any solution to the `ERROR: Failed to unpack received packet.` or `ERROR: Failed to confirm end of file transfer sequence!`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Regards, ConDar